# PHP Custom Namespace not working

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I just finished building a site locally via Xampp. Everything is working just fine, its using PHP version 5.6. I used composer to use some third party apps such as Guzzle and Stringy. After done I uploaded to my Godaddy webhosting account, which uses PHP 5.5. When I load the site I get this error:

Fatal error: Class 'Libs\Model\Site_Settings' not found in public_html/portal/conf/settings.php on line 81

However the vendor namespaces work just fine. I dont get any errors. Heck I dont get any errors with my custom classes. I am using composer to autoload everything. Everything works perfectly locally, just any classes that I use custom namespaces for do not work only on my web hosting account. In my classes I have at the top:

```
namespace Libs\Model;
```

I also tried using brackets

```
namespace Libs\Model {\\code here}
```

Tried researching the issue, coming up with nothing. Any suggestions? In the psr4 autoload file it shows:

```
'Libs\\' => array($baseDir . '/lib')
```

I verified $baseDir is pointed to the correct folder.

**UPDATE**

Here is code from the class Im trying to call. Very simple:

```
namespace Libs\Model;

class Site_Settings {

    private $dbconn;

    public function __construct($dbconn)
    {

        $this->dbconn = $dbconn;            

    }

    public function findSiteSettings($domain)
    {

        //We clean any variables being passed to the query
        $domain = $this->dbconn->escape($domain);

        //We turn on query caching
        $this->dbconn->cache_queries = TRUE;

        //This is the query statement to run
        $query = $this->dbconn->get_row("
                SELECT
                    jp.*,
                    js.stateabb,
                    js.statename,
                    js.statecountry
                FROM
                    job_site AS jp
                INNER JOIN
                    job_state AS js
                ON
                    jp.stateid = js.id
                WHERE
                    jp.sitedomain = '$domain'
                AND
                    jp.active = 1
                LIMIT
                    1
                ");

        //We turn off query caching
        $this->dbconn->cache_queries = FALSE;

        //We now return any rows found
        return $query;

    }

}
```

This is how Im calling it:

```
//We include the autoloader that is needed to load all vendors for this site
    include(VENDORS .'autoload.php');

    //We get the site settings for this job site
    $settings = new Libs\Model\Site_Settings($global_db);
    $site_settings = $settings->findSiteSettings($global_sitedomain);
```

This is my autoload file for psr4 from composer:

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname(dirname($vendorDir));

return array(
    'Symfony\\Polyfill\\Mbstring\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-mbstring'),
    'Stringy\\' => array($vendorDir . '/danielstjules/stringy/src'),
    'Psr\\Http\\Message\\' => array($vendorDir . '/psr/http-message/src'),
    'Libs\\' => array($baseDir . '/lib'),
    'League\\Plates\\' => array($vendorDir . '/league/plates/src'),
    'GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzlehttp/psr7/src'),
    'GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzlehttp/promises/src'),
    'GuzzleHttp\\' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src'),
    'Cocur\\Slugify\\' => array($vendorDir . '/cocur/slugify/src'),
);
```

**UPDATE #2**
Here is my composer file

```
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "lib/vendor/ezsql/mysqli/ez_sql_mysqli.php",
            "lib/vendor/ezsql/shared/ez_sql_core.php",
            "lib/helper/url.php",
            "lib/helper/html.php",
            "lib/helper/form_message.php",
            "lib/helper/email_generator.php",
            "lib/helper/pagination.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {"Libs\\": "lib"}
    },
    "require": {
        "league/plates": "^3.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2",
        "cocur/slugify": "^2.1",
        "danielstjules/stringy": "^2.3",
        "wixel/gump": "^1.3",
        "jwage/purl": "^0.0.7"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information to really answer your question.  Where is the php file located for Libs\Model\Site_Settings?  Are you working on a case insensitive system like OSX and uploading to a case sensitive one like Linux?  What auto-loading standard are you using?  It looks like you are using both PSR-0 and PSR-4.

You may need to add a autoload path to your composer.json:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Libs\\Model\\": "lib/src/model",
```

Comment: Where is Site_Settings.php in relation to ./vendor/

Comment: From the main directory its: \lib\vendor\model\site_settings.php Oh man is this a case sensitive issue? Crap if this is it Im stupid as hell

Comment: Nope, changed file name from site_settings.php to Site_Settings.php and still same error...

Comment: Wait I think I know the issue.

Comment: Yep wow, Im an idiot. Sorry for wasting your time. The folder model needed to be capitalized... Geez man... Thanks for your help